# Django Context rendering - django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key

Tags: python, django

I am facing an issue to render Django Context Dictionary.
I have tried multiple options but could not able to render the context. In the debug logs I am seeing error for "VariableDoesNotExit".

Here is my sample code:

**Views.py**

```
def KpiEngine(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = KpiEngineForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            report_group = form.cleaned_data['report_group']
            domain = form.cleaned_data['domain']
            report_type = form.cleaned_data['report_type']
            report_sub_type = form.cleaned_data['sub_report_type']
            report_period = form.cleaned_data['report_period']
            
            my_context = {"a":1}
            return render(request,'core_pmapp/kpitool.html',{'form':form},my_context)
        else:
            my_context = {"a":1}
            return render(request,'core_pmapp/kpitool.html',{'form':form},my_context)

    else:
        context = {}
        form = KpiEngineForm()
        return render(request,'core_pmapp/kpitool.html',{'form':form})
```

**Here is my template:**

```
<div class="container p-0">
    <div class="card bg-light">
        <div class="card-header p-4"> KPI Engine</div>
        {% if a == 1 %}
        <div class="card-body h-200 col-5 p-4 ml-2">
            <p> Report Generation is in progress</p>
            <p> It might take few minutes .....</p>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="card-body col-5 p-4 ml-2">
            <form action="" method="GET,POST">

                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4 p-2">

                        Report Group
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 p-2">
                        {{ form.report_group }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 p-2">
                        Domain
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 p-2">
                        {{ form.domain }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 p-2">
                        Report Type
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 p-2">
                        {{ form.report_type }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 p-2">
                        Report Sub Type
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 p-2">
                        {{ form.sub_report_type }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 p-2">
                        Report Period
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 p-2">
                        {{ form.report_period }}
                    </div>
                    <input class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" value="submit">
                </div>
                </table>
                {% endif %}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ERROR logs:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 835, in _resolve_lookup
    if isinstance(current, BaseContext) and getattr(type(current), bit):
AttributeError: type object 'RequestContext' has no attribute 'a'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 848, in _resolve_lookup
    raise VariableDoesNotExist("Failed lookup for key "
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [a] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: <function csrf.<locals>._get_val at 0x7f3d1d849dc0>>, 'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/core_pmapp/corepmeng?
```

Can someone please help resolve the problem ?

Ankit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update `return` statements like this;

`return render(request,'core_pmapp/kpitool.html',{'form':form, **my_context})`

Also notice that you don't return key named `a` in `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

@lab.ankit - The logs suggest that you are trying to render the template in a GET request. However, you are not passing the context variable "a". Most likely that is causing the error. :

```
context = {}
    form = KpiEngineForm()
    return render(request,'core_pmapp/kpitool.html',{'form':form})
```

One way to resolve this would be to do a check-in your template like `{% if a%}....{%endif%}`then put your logic inside the if block.